# gnome-shell extensions panel position

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

Is it possible to change the extension position(by modifying the extension.js) in gnome-shell status area? I mean that I'd like to see the language indicator in the first position(from left to right), cuz it's visually easier to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using information from [this page](http://notsnippets.tumblr.com/post/10799581696/notes-on-writing-gnome-shell-extensions) we can deduce that you need to change the line in the extension.js that says

```
Main.panel.addToStatusArea([sometext],[othertext])
```

to

```
Main.panel.addToStatusArea([sometext], [othertext], 1)
```

After modifying the extension.js file, hit Alt+F2 and then put 'r' in the box and hit enter.

I haven't found any central source to reference the gnome-shell JavaScript API (called GJS). Would be really handy if there was one easily accessible.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to evaluate Panel from the linked code. The code is now correct.

Comment: hm, I'm trying to move all-in-one-places extension and it's not working this way    Main.panel.addToStatusArea('all-in-one-places', _indicator, 0);

Comment: Let me see if I can get it working.

Comment: I got it to work just fine. However, mine was already in position 0 and I moved it to position 1. Remember, that to reload the modified extension you have to press Alt+F2, enter 'r' into the box and hit enter. This will reload gnome-shell.

Comment: awesome, it appeared I needed to move it to position 1,sou the language indicator become the position 0.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I misunderstood the post. I'll modify my answer again. And thanks for the best answer ;)